# Incorrect fomat (wrong number of columns) after writing to csv files

Tags: python, csv, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

My intention is to get the full review of all the profiles along with title of the review, user name, location of the user and the time of posting from the reliance jio reviews web pages of the website and store it in a CSV file.

The website I want to crawl is http://www.mouthshut.com/mobile-operators/Reliance-Jio-reviews-925812061

When I tried storing the scraped data of first two pages in a CSV file, I got the below output. **My problem** is the output in each line generate more columns than desired. One sentence is parsed into many cells.

### [image: Screenshot of CSV file containing scraped data]

My code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from selenium import webdriver;import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import csv

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] = '/etc/firefox'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
url = "http://www.mouthshut.com/mobile-operators/Reliance-Jio-reviews-925812061"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for items1 in    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".review-article"))):
   link1 = items1.find_element_by_css_selector(".reviewdata a")
   link1.click()
   time.sleep(2)
csv = open('index.csv','w')
column = "Name,Location,Review_data,Review_title,Review_data\n"
csv.write(column)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for item1 in soup1.select(".review-article"):
   name1 = item1.select("p a")[0].text
   location1 = item1.select("p")[1].text
   review_date1 = item1.select("small")[0].text
   review_title1 = item1.select("strong  a[id^=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFooter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_rptreviews]")[0].text
   review_data1 = ' '.join([' '.join(items1.text.split()) for items1 in   item1.select(".reviewdata")])
   print("Name: {}\nLocation : {}\nReview_date: {}\nReview_Title: {}\nReview_Data: {}\n".format(name1, location1, review_date1, review_title1, review_data1))
   csv1 = open('index.csv','a')
   page1_data = name1 + "," + location1 + "," + review_date1 + "," + review_title1  + "," + review_data1  + "\n" 
   csv1.write(page1_data)
uclient=uReq(url)
page_html=uclient.read()
uclient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
container = soup.find("ul",{"class":"pages table"})
all_li = container.findAll("li")
last_div = None
for last_div in all_li:pass
if last_div:
   content = last_div.getText()
   content1 = int(content)
   container1 = soup.findAll("li",{"class":"next"})
   li=container1[0].find("a",{"class":"btn btn-link"}).attrs['href']    
driver.get(li)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".review-article"))):
   link = items.find_element_by_css_selector(".reviewdata a")
   link.click()
   time.sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for item in soup.select(".review-article"):
    name = item.select("p a")[0].text
    location = item.select("p")[1].text
    review_date = item.select("small")[0].text
    review_title = item.select("strong a[id^=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFooter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_rptreviews]")[0].text
    review_data = ' '.join([' '.join(items.text.split()) for items in item.select(".reviewdata")])
    print("Name: {}\nLocation : {}\nReview_date: {}\nReview_Title: {}\nReview_Data: {}\n".format(name, location, review_date, review_title, review_data))
    csv2 = open("index.csv",'a')
    page2_data = name  +","+ location+"," + review_date +","+ review_title +","+ review_data + "\n"
    csv2.write(page2_data)
    driver.quit()
```

I need help to figure out the error in my code for storing the scraped data into the CSV file in a structured manner.

Comment: better use module `csv`to save data - it seems you have comma in some text and now it treats this text as many columns. With module `csv` you wouldn't have this problem because it would put text in extra `" "`. It also resolves problem when there is "enter"/"new line" in data.

Comment: Can you help me by updating the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

```
page1_data = name1 + "," + location1 + "," + review_date1 + "," + review_title1  + "," + review_data1  + "\n" 
csv1.write(page1_data)
```

There is already comma used in, say, location: Delhi, India. If you keep using comma like you did above, the csv file cannot be parsed properly.

**One workaround is to put "" around your text containing comma. So the Delhi, India would be turned into "\Delhi, India" after this step. **

```
def preprocess(text):
    if "," in text:
        return '"' + text + '"'
    return text
```

Wrap each of your text with the function.

```
page1_data = preprocess(name1) + "," + preprocess(location1) + "," + preprocess(review_date1) + "," + preprocess(review_title1)  + "," + preprocess(review_data1)  + "\n"
```

This should work.

Another way should be changing the delimiter to other characters.

Comment: Can you give the sample code for the same? Since I am a beginner to python, I am getting confused for the steps to do this.

Comment: @Monisha Try this.

Comment: I did a modification to the function to concatenate the spaces in the text and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

View your csv file in a text editor.  The problem is your spreadsheet program is parsing on BOTH commas and spaces.

Another problem is that you haven't accounted for commas WITHIN your scraped data.  That is why you have the city and country in different cells.  You will need to put quotation marks around values that have commas within them.

Comment: I don't know how to put the double quotes for a variable name since the variable name will be considered as a string if we put double quotes to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `csv` module because it will automatically resolve problem with comma and "new line"/enter in text.

Create csv writer

```
f = open('index.csv','w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
```

and write headers using list, not single string

```
column = ["Name", "Location", "Review_data", "Review_title", "Review_data"]
csv_writer.writerow(column)
```

the same way write list with data

```
row = [name, location, review_date, review_title, review_data]
csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Full code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from selenium import webdriver;import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import csv

# --- init ---

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] = '/etc/firefox'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
url = "http://www.mouthshut.com/mobile-operators/Reliance-Jio-reviews-925812061"

# --- open file ---

f = open("index.csv", "w")
csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

columns = ["Name", "Location", "Review_data", "Review_title", "Review_data"]
csv_writer.writerow(columns)

# ---- get data ---

driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".review-article"))):
   link = items.find_element_by_css_selector(".reviewdata a")
   link.click()
   time.sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

for item in soup.select(".review-article"):
    name = item.select("p a")[0].text
    location = item.select("p")[1].text
    review_date = item.select("small")[0].text
    review_title = item.select("strong  a[id^=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFooter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_rptreviews]")[0].text
    review_data = ' '.join([' '.join(items.text.split()) for items in item.select(".reviewdata")])

    print("Name:", name)
    print("Location:", location)
    print("Review_date:", review_date)
    print("Review_Title:", review_title)
    print("Review_Data:", review_data)

    row = [name, location, review_date, review_title, review_data]
    csv_writer.writerow(row)

# --- get next url ---

uclient = uReq(url)
page_html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
container = soup.find("ul", {"class": "pages table"})

all_li = container.findAll("li")
if all_li:
    last_div = all_li[-1]
    content = last_div.getText()
    content = int(content)
    container = soup.findAll("li", {"class": "next"})
    li = container[0].find("a", {"class": "btn btn-link"}).attrs['href']

# ---- get data ---

driver.get(li)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".review-article"))):
    link = items.find_element_by_css_selector(".reviewdata a")
    link.click()
    time.sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
for item in soup.select(".review-article"):
    name = item.select("p a")[0].text
    location = item.select("p")[1].text
    review_date = item.select("small")[0].text
    review_title = item.select("strong a[id^=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFooter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_rptreviews]")[0].text
    review_data = ' '.join([' '.join(items.text.split()) for items in item.select(".reviewdata")])

    print("Name:", name)
    print("Location:", location)
    print("Review_date:", review_date)
    print("Review_Title:", review_title)
    print("Review_Data:", review_data)

    row = [name, location, review_date, review_title, review_data]
    csv_writer.writerow(row)

# --- end ---

driver.quit()
f.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** version without `beautifulsoup` and `requests` - only `selenium`

```
from selenium import webdriver;import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import csv

def get_data(driver, csv_writer):

    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".review-article"):
        name = item.find_elements_by_css_selector("p a")[0].text
        location = item.find_elements_by_css_selector("p")[1].text
        review_date = item.find_elements_by_css_selector("small")[0].text
        review_title = item.find_elements_by_css_selector("strong  a[id^=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderFooter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_rptreviews]")[0].text
        review_data = item.find_elements_by_css_selector(".reviewdata")
        review_data = ' '.join([' '.join(items.text.split()) for items in review_data])

        print("Name:", name)
        print("Location:", location)
        print("Review_date:", review_date)
        print("Review_Title:", review_title)
        print("Review_Data:", review_data)

        row = [name, location, review_date, review_title, review_data]
        csv_writer.writerow(row)

# --- init ---

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] = '/etc/firefox'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
url = "http://www.mouthshut.com/mobile-operators/Reliance-Jio-reviews-925812061"

# --- open file ---

f = open("index.csv", "w")
csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

columns = ["Name", "Location", "Review_data", "Review_title", "Review_data"]
csv_writer.writerow(columns)

# ---- get data ---

print('url:', url)

driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

get_data(driver, csv_writer)

# --- get next url ---

url = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a').get_attribute("href")

# ---- get data ---

print('url:', url)

driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

get_data(driver, csv_writer)

# --- end ---

driver.quit()
f.close()
```